# How to use gethostbyname_r in linux

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming

I am currently using thread unsafe **gethostbyname** version which is very easy to use. You pass the hostname and it returns me the address structure. Looks like in MT environment, this version is crashing my application so trying to replace it with **gethostbyname_r**. Finding it very difficult to google a sample usage or any good documentation.

Has anybody used this **gethostbyname_r** method ? any ideas ? How to use it and how to handle its error conditions if any.

Comment: Found one blog about this but the code is not working. http://dimitry-i.blogspot.com/2010/09/how-to-use-gethostbynamer-correct.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function is using a temporary buffer supplied by the caller. The trick is to handle the `ERANGE` error.

```
int rc, err;
char *str_host;
struct hostent hbuf;
struct hostent *result;

while ((rc = gethostbyname_r(str_host, &hbuf, buf, len, &result, &err)) == ERANGE) {
    /* expand buf */
    len *= 2;
    void *tmp = realloc(buf, buflen);
    if (NULL == tmp) {
        free(buf);
        perror("realloc");
    }else{
        buf = tmp;
    }
}

if (0 != rc || NULL == result) {
    perror("gethostbyname");
}
```

EDIT

In light of recent comments I guess what you really want is [`getaddrinfo`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html).

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how to derive server_addr.sin_addr which I need to pass to the socket connect call ?

Comment: @harry See my edited answer. If you don't get `getaddrinfo` (or plain don't like it) ask another question.

Comment: Though rare, but assigning the return value of realloc to the original pointer variable may cause memory leakage.

Comment: @felix021 Why would that happen? I fail to see it.

Comment: buflen in realloc call should be len.  @eduardo is correct, realloc is used correctly here, though it should be pointed out that at some point buf needs to be free()d after it is used.